# Couchbase BulkGet in spring data couchbase

Tags: spring-data, couchbase

I am using Couchbase with Spring Data and wish to implement `bulkGet` of Couchbase. Please let me know the following:

1. Is it possible via Spring Data?

   - If yes, can you share an example?
2. Is `findAll` (using `_all` view) comparable to `bulkGet` in terms of performance?
3. Can I fetch the `_id` along with the Couchbase document?

Environment:- Couchbase 4.0, Spring Data 2.0.0.RELEASE, Java 8.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking about a bulk get in the context of repositories.

First, there is currently no complete support of a "bulkGet" in Spring Data Couchbase. Most of the implementation is based on the SDK synchronous API, and bulk get is something usually done using the **asynchronous** API, using `RxJava`.

Note that there is no actual "bulkGet" operation at the protocol level in Couchbase, it's just the SDK issuing multiple single `Get` and batching them together.

To answer your second question, the above is important. The bulk get pattern discussed in the Couchbase Java SDK documentation (here) gives a slight performance boost because unlike in synchronous mode, we don't wait for the retrieval of one item to get the next.

The `findAll()` and `findAll(Iterable)` methods in Spring Data Couchbase both operate on top of a `view`, which allows to only retrieve documents that match the entity type of your repository but introduces a level of indirection that can lower performance compared to a pure sequence of key/value gets.

So the closest you could get to a bulk operation like that in Spring Data Couchbase would be to **know all the IDs** you're interested in and then **perform a `findOne` per ID**.

In the near term, the code behind the `findAll(Iterable)` signature could maybe be improved by applying a bulk get pattern on all provided IDs, but that would mean forgetting about the type checking induced by the view, so I'm not sure...